# Insert a new row in jTable automatically while entering data in the last row

Tags: java, swing, jtable, actionlistener

**What I have done til now?**

I've created a business application which needs the information to be added with the help of a jTable. Below is the image of my jTable.[image]

The '+' button here adds a new row while '-' button removes the selected row on clicking the respective buttons.

**What I need?**

I need an idea about any event or something which insert a new row after the last row while the user starts adding data to the last row at runtime.

Specifically, I don't need any button event to add rows. The row must be automatically inserted while the last row is not empty anymore.

Please Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try it with a `TableModelListener`. Basic idea: you get notified, whenever a cell was edited. You can then check if the cell was in the last row, and if it was, add a new row to the table.

```
DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel();
JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);

tableModel.addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
  @Override
  public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
    if ((e.getLastRow() + 1) == tableModel.getRowCount()) {
      // something was entered into the last row, add a new row
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @cello. It worked like a charm. and what condition should I use if I want to remove all the blank rows?

Comment: Removing empty rows might be harder, as one has to ensure that the user is no longer editing the row (none of the cells has the focus). I would ask that as a new question.

Comment: This leads to an endless loop for me, Every time a row is added with tableModel.addRow, it fires a new tableChanged event and therefore adds another row.